# Cannot read error of http request response

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, cycle, xstream

I'm currently using redux-cycles in my React native app to make an API request. This is what my cycle looks like:

```
const handleAction$ = ACTION
.filter(({ type }) => type === Types.MY_THING)
.map(({ stuff }) => stuff)
.compose(fooBar())
.map(() => ({
  url: 'bad_url_for_testing',
  method: 'POST',
}))

const continue$ = HTTP
  .select('sendStuff')
  // check for error
  .map(response$ => response$.replaceError(err => xs.of(err.response)))
  .flatten()
  // choose the correct action
  // this is where it fails!
  .map((res) =>
    res.error
    ? Creators.failureAction()
    : Creators.successAction()
  );
return {
  HTTP: handleAction$,
  ACTION: continue$
}
```

Upon running the cycle, however, I will get the following error:

`Cannot read property 'error' of undefined`

What is the issue?

Thanks in advance